# Root directory of my git project deleted, and I have no idea why

Tags: git

This is the output of `git status`:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
      (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
      (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

           deleted:    FreeCodeCamp

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

`FreeCodeCamp` is the root directory of my git project, and as such I can't perform ANY git commands. I have no idea how this happened, but it may be  helpful to know what my common git commands are. On a regular basis, I simply add files to my git repo and then push them to the remote at the end of the day.

Does anyone know how this happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> FreeCodeCamp is the root directory of my git project, and as such I can't perform ANY git commands.

I don't think that's true. If `FreeCodeCamp` were your root directory you wouldn't be able to run `git status` to show the output in your question.

This recommendation from `git status` is a good one:

> ```
> use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory
> ```

Running `git checkout -- FreeCodeCamp` should restore your directory.

Comment: Can you think of a reason of why this happened?

Comment: @SalP., it's unlikely that it was a Git command. Something like `git rm`, for example, would have staged the deletion as well. Anything that would have deleted that directory or moved it elsewhere (a misclick in a file manager, for example) could have led to this.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!